# Ravendb Nodejs, using Enums in the map index

Tags: node.js, indexing, nestjs, ravendb

I use ravendb in nestjs

I have an enum in the library project (core library):

```
export enum GroupType {
    Agent = "agent",
    System = "system"
}
```

and I import and use that enum in the index logic (raven project)

```
import { Models } from '@ply/core';
        
export class Agents_All extends AbstractJavaScriptMultiMapIndexCreationTask<AgentResult> {
        this.map<IUser>(User, user => {
            if(user.groupType === Models.Enums.GroupType.Agent){
```

**Q1 :**
**how can I use my enums or constants in the map index, should I export them to the Ravendb as an additional source? export enum like a function?**

and below is the generated map index on the Ravendb side :
[image]
**Q2 :
why did Ravendb add the project's name of the enum as a namespace before the enum**

*Models.Enums.GroupType.Agent* **converted to** *core_1.Models.Enums.GroupType.Agent*

Comment: for node.js - there is a related open issue: https://issues.hibernatingrhinos.com/issue/RDBC-646/nodejs-investigate-if-we-can-use-enums-in-strongly-typed-index-definiton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We implemented this feature and in order to use such enum, you should register it via `this.registerEnum(() => RoleString.Admin);` call. Then you can use such enum inside map/reduce function and it is replaced with correct enum value.

```
enum RoleNumber {
    Admin,
    User
}


class User {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    roleString: RoleString;
    roleNumber: RoleNumber;
}

class UsersByStringRole extends AbstractJavaScriptIndexCreationTask<User, Pick<User, "name" | "roleString">> {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.registerEnum(() => (RoleString.Admin));

        this.map(User, u => {
            if (u.roleString === RoleString.Admin) {
                return ({
                    name: u.name,
                    roleString: u.roleString
                });
            }
            return null;
        });
    }
}

class UsersByNumberRole extends AbstractJavaScriptIndexCreationTask<User, Pick<User, "name" | "roleNumber">> {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.registerEnum(() => RoleNumber.Admin);

        this.map(User, u => {
            if (u.roleNumber === RoleNumber.Admin) {
                return ({
                    name: u.name,
                    roleNumber: u.roleNumber
                });
            }
            return null;
        });
    }
}
```